# SSRS additional unwanted columns when exporting report to excel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reportingservices-2005

I know this question of avoiding unwanted columns when exporting Excel has probably been over done and has an obvious solution to try that is align your textbox to the nearest tablix column but it does not work for me.

I have isolated down to:

- First/Top section - 2 textboxes, 2nd aligned under the first that has a width that spans over 11 columns to the tablix below, followed next to it on the right by an image (fit Proptional) that's height is greater than the 2 textboxes combined, but width is the same as the 12th column.
- Followed by the tablix

I can assure you everything aligns exactly down to the 5th decimal point in cm which leads me to the possibility that do I need to use less decimal point accuracy. I.e. when you resize columns manually by dragging the widths can sometimes go down to the 5 decimal point. When exported to excel I have 2 extra columns either side of my image.

I even decided on an alternative method by first adding a new header row to my tablix at the top and merge the first 11 columns and insert a rectangle then placed my 2 textboxes into it then in the 12th column my image. This time when exported I only get an additional column on the left hand-side a small consolation. My textboxes I mentioned there widths are 23.45188cm aligned exactly to the width of my rectangle that sits inside my 11 column merged cell. So there is no reason for this annoying addition column or is there?

If I don't get a good solution soon in the meantime I will have to experiment by setting the columns widths to less decimal points or even try inches.

Probably somebody will be kind enough to tell me it is a rendering bug in the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Typical Microsoft don't use cm's is my own advise I used inches to 1 decimal point for all my widths of columns and textboxes and now no additional columns. Yee ha! That is an another hour of my time I wont get back.